# Lightning Component Error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have implemented functionality to accept user input. In this we have single select questions for which we are using radio input.
Following is the code :

```
<aura:renderIf isTrue='{!question.answer == opt}'>
<input type="radio" value="{!question.id}" name="{!questionNumber}" onchange="{!c.onRadioSelect}"  title="{!opt}" checked='checked'/>{!opt}
<aura:set attribute='else'>
<input type="radio" value="{!question.id}" name="{!questionNumber}" onchange="{!c.onRadioSelect}"  title="{!opt}"/>{!opt}
</aura:set>
</aura:renderIf>
```

Here, question.answer = selected answer ( Saved in object )

{!opt} = label of input radio

When we are trying to load lightning component for existing result, it is throwing following error.

[image]

*Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Invalid component tried calling function [get] with arguments [v.items.0]*

We have also tried to use  , but design is not working for this properly, also it won't render on iPhone properly.

If anyone has faced similar issue or has any idea , please let me know.
Thanks ,

Comment: can you add your controller.js to this question. it seems error is there when you are using v.items

Comment: @Himanshu : Unfortunately I can share below small piece of code only.
    onRadioSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
        var radioValue = $(event.target).attr("title");
        var questionId = $(event.target).attr("value");
        //-- saving this value in an array       
    }